# Binding events to newly added html content AJAX Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, events

I have a sample web program that manage colleges. By the time the document loads, an ajax is invoked to request for the colleges data.

A request is also invoked when adding a new college. By the time when inserting to mysql is successful and done, the ajax call for college data is invoked again.

```
$(document).on("click", ".ctrl-btn", function(e){
  if($(this).hasClass("college-edit-btn")) {
    $(".college-edit-btn").on("click", editCollegeProcess);
  }
});
//The editCollegeProcess() simply alerts the id of the parent.
```

The code works but I do have to double click the button to trigger the function by the time the document is loaded. When clicking the button while the alert window is active, it fires the event as well.

I hope I explained it clearly, Please help. It's so confusing @@

Comment: It's almost never right to put one event handler inside another event handler.

Comment: remove inside `"click"` binding and use it outside like this `$(document).on("click", ".college-edit-btn", editCollegeProcess);`

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan Thank you so much. I'm so stupid.

Comment: @EhmzYoshinoMamei let me put this useful comment as answer so that it helps others :)

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan been struggling hours for this hahahaa yeah thanks a lot again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove inside `"click"` binding and use it outside like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".college-edit-btn", editCollegeProcess);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not binding the `.college-edit-btn` handler until after the user clicks on `.ctrl-btn` first . You should just put the event delegation directly in the main code.

```
$(document).on("click", ".college-edit-btn", editCollegeProcess);
```

Comment: it looks same like my comment BTW.

Answer (score 0):

If you must have 2 click events, you can just chain them:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".ctrl-btn", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();//if necessary 
}).on('click', 'college-edit-btn', editCollegeProcess{

});
```

Assuming there is a parent-child relationship.